# is there any API calls available to check the support cycle for the LTS

Tags: server, lts

Does ubuntu have any api calls available to check the LTS support cycle ? Like till what year do we have support provided for the each releases. I know the following link provide the details,[ubuntu release cycle](https://ubuntu.com/about/release-cycle), curious of we have an api using which we can check the end date of a particular release.

Comment: Why would you need it? Releases are not so often to check dates using an API.

Comment: The exact date could be around the 21st of the month for when it was released or when it goes EOL.  If you're curious as to when you have updates for you can always run `ubuntu-security-status`.

Comment: @Pilot6 : I was trying to create a solution in which i need to check the current distros eol so that i can update the respective owners about the same. Since we can use the command to see till what year the updates are available is also possible to use. However if we have any api requests that can actually fetch data from the ubuntu form would have been better. This was my thought while posting the question here.

Answer (score 1):

There is `ubuntu-security-status`:

```
~$ ubuntu-security-status 
1819 packages installed, of which:
1510 receive package updates with LTS until 4/2025
   2 packages are from third parties

Packages from third parties are not provided by the official Ubuntu
archive, for example packages from Personal Package Archives in
Launchpad.
For more information on the packages, run 'ubuntu-security-status
--thirdparty'.
```